# File operations not permitted on ntfs file system on Thoshiba 1TB external hard disk in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

Recently I buy a Thoshiba external hard disk. And I make a NTFS partition. Now it is read only mode in Ubuntu 11.10. Now I can't able to copy from my system / create folder in HDD. But copying from external HDD is permitted (writing is not permitted).

Could you please help to fix my bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Install NTFS Config.  To do that, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

once the installation is done, create the dirictories below:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/hal
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

And then do:

```
sudo ntfs-config
```

When the application runs, just check Enable write support for external device, and click close.

[image]

Comment: sudo ntfs-config
 is not working

Comment: The error now is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ntfs-config", line 102, in <module>
    main(args, opts)
  File "/usr/bin/ntfs-config", line 75, in main
    app = NtfsConfig()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/NtfsConfig/NtfsConfig.py", line 56, in __init__
    os.mkdir(HAL_CONFIG_DIR)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/hal/fdi/policy'

Comment: I just installed 11.10 to see what the problem is, and I have updated the answer to reflect that.